# Toggle Class issue when Event Handlers are needed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have a couple of td elements I would like to make editable and then when a button is clicked have them revert to static. The problem is getting these elements to toggle back and forth. How do I accomplish this in the easiest way possible?

It seems recursive where I would click edit -> replace the elements with input elements -> give button static function handler -> click button -> replace the input with static content -> add event handler. The only issue I have is attaching the handler to the newly created elements.

Javascript:

```
// how do I encapsulate this into its own function? Seems recursive.
$('.edit-me').click(function(){
    // remove the other editable fields.

  // For some reason the second toggle errors out. - Why?
  makeEditable(this);
  $(this).toggleClass('edit-me');
  $(this).toggleClass('static-me');
});

    // attach a handler to the newly created elements
    $('.static-me').click(function(){
        // this is not working because newly created items do not have the event associated to them.
        console.log("HERE");
        makeStatic(this);
        $(this).toggleClass('edit-me');
        $(this).toggleClass('static-me');
    });
}
$('.delete-me').click(function(){
    pair_delete(this);
});
function makeEditable(obj){
    // replace the elements with an editable element.
    $(obj).parent().children('td.editable').each(function(index, item){
        $(item).html('<input class="form-control edit-mode editing" data-field="' +  $(this).attr('data-field') + '" value="' + $(this).html() + '" >');
        // toggle for event handling.
        $(item).removeClass('editable');
        $(item).addClass('edit-mode');
    });
    $('.editing').change(function(){
        // create the update
        pair_update(this);
    });
}
function makeStatic(obj){
    // makes the row static.
    $(obj).parent().children('td.edit-mode').each(function(index, item){
        // replace with input field.
        $(item).html('<td class="editable" data-field="'+ $(item).attr('data-field') +'">' + $(item).find('.editing').val() + '</td>');
        $(item).addClass('editable');
        $(item).removeClass('edit-mode');
    });
}
```

HTML:

```
<td class="editable" data-field="pair_name"><?=$pair['pair_name']?></td>
    <td class="editable" data-field="email_name"><?=$pair['email_id']?></td>
    <td class="editable" data-field="sent_event_id"><?=$pair['sent_event_id']?></td>
<td class="editable" data-field="minutes"><?=$pair['minutes']?></td>
    <td class="edit-me">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil icon-white"></i>
</button>
</td>
```

Comment: Read http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events

Answer (score 1):

if you'd rather keep to toggling, use `.on('click', '.classname', function() { // do stuff here; });` instead of `.click()` (it should solve the bindings to the new elements on the dom)

another solution is to try something without toggle, since toggle gets messy with switching out elements and such. something more straight forward like this could work : http://jsfiddle.net/swm53ran/177/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('table').on('click', '.edit', function() {
        var name = $(this).closest('tr').find('.name').html();
        var email = $(this).closest('tr').find('.email').html();
        $(this).closest('tr').find('.name').html('<input type="text" value="'+ name +'"/>');
        $(this).closest('tr').find('.email').html('<input type="text" value="'+ email +'"/>');
        $(this).closest('tr').find('.edit').closest('td').html('<a href="#" class="save">Save</a>');
    });

    $('table').on('click', '.save', function() {
        var name = $(this).closest('tr').find('.name').find('input').val();
        var email = $(this).closest('tr').find('.email').find('input').val();
        $(this).closest('tr').find('.name').html(name);
        $(this).closest('tr').find('.email').html(email);
        $(this).closest('tr').find('.save').closest('td').html('<a href="#" class="edit">Edit</a>');
    });

});

<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="name">Name1</td>
        <td class="email">Email1</td>
        <td class="action"><a href="#" class="edit">Edit</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="name">Name2</td>
        <td class="email">Email2</td>
        <td class="action"><a href="#" class="edit">Edit</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="name">Name3</td>
        <td class="email">Emaiil3</td>
        <td class="action"><a href="#" class="edit">Edit</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```